# Node.js with Socket.io working locally but not remotely (request IP changed remote)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, localhost, http-status-code-404

I feel I have exhausted all the related posts and solutions I can find, without resolution, and none with the exact issue I am seeing (although many very similar).

In short, I have a very simple example of a NodeJS socket.io emitter and a client.
It runs as expected when the client web page is hosted on the same host as nodeJS socket.io emitter app. The same client web page executed from any other host gives the same issue.

Essentially I get continuous messages as follows;

```
404 [XHR]       http://192.168.0.41/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NGc5_Pg
```

I will explain the details below, but the smoking gun I believe is that the IP address/host of that request has been changed to that hosting the client web page.

When running on the same host (192.168.0.35) I get the following success;

```
200 [XHR]       http://192.168.0.35:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NGc1BqD
101 [WebSocket] ws://192.168.0.35:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=jIxHFTv6eoIXXGiRAAAH    
200 [XHR]       http://192.168.0.35:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NGc1Bqi&sid=jIxHFTv6eoIXXGiRAAAH
```

**When run remotely, the IP address is the web page server host now !**
(I am sure there is something simple causing this I do not understand)
Why is the request IP now .41 and not .35 ???

Here is the more complete comparison of the two tests;

**WORKING** : client page served same host as node emitter

```
200 [XHR]       http://192.168.0.35:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js                                                     Content-Type: application/javascript
200 [XHR]       http://192.168.0.35:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NGc1BqD                               Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
101 [WebSocket] ws://192.168.0.35:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=jIxHFTv6eoIXXGiRAAAH                Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
200 [XHR]       http://192.168.0.35:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NGc1Bqi&sid=jIxHFTv6eoIXXGiRAAAH      Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

**FAILED** : client page served ANY other host

```
200 [script]    http://192.168.0.35:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js                                                     Content-Type: application/javascript
404 [XHR]       http://192.168.0.41/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NGc5_Pg                                
404 [XHR]       http://192.168.0.41/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NGc61sS
404 [XHR]       http://192.168.0.41/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NGc5_l5
...
...
... infinity
```

Note that the port 3000 is OPEN, and is successfully serving the socket.io.js.
Also it does not seem to matter  what is hosting the client web page (nginx, node, etc)

When run remotely I am not seeing any CORS or XSS errors - which I suppose makes sense - since the request is being changed to local IP/domain ?

I would greatly appreciate any help in seeing where I am failing to understand something or what I am missing !

Here is the code;

**node testsockets.js**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");  
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);  
    res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "script-src 'self'");
    next();
  });

var options = {
  allowUpgrades: true,
  transports: ['websocket', 'file', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'polling'],
  pingTimeout: 9000,
  pingInterval: 3000,
  httpCompression: true,
  origins: '*:*' 
};

var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http, options);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

sub_client.subscribe('datahub.tsv.environment');

sub_client.on("message", function(channel, message){
   io.emit('event message', message);
   console.log("redis subscription message: " + JSON.stringify(message));
});

http.listen(3000, '192.168.0.35', () => {
  console.log('dataHUB NodeJS Redis Subscriber listening on *:3000');
});
```

**client HTML page**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Socket.IO Event Messages</title>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://192.168.0.35:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

<script>
  'use strict';

    let socket = io();
    socket.connect('http://192.168.0.35:3000');

    socket.on('event message', function(msg){
       $("p").html( msg);
    });
</script>

  <body>
    <div id="display" style="width:100%;">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with client side code . It is not able to connect to the URL you are passing.
Try let socket = io('http://192.168.0.35:3000'); or other way like io.connect(URL) .

By default socket.io in the client tries to connect to the server/host it is served from, if URL is not provided. It is not able to get the .35 IP URL , so it is trying to connect to .41 since it is hosted and served there.

Luckily, when both server and client are together, it is working because the client by default is trying to connect to the server that is serving the client, that is .35 IP. It did not take the correct URL you passed even there, but the default matched the socket server!

Comment: Hi - I am not sure I understand how that is different from the code I am using ?  I am in fact using i.connect(URL). Perhaps I am not understanding correctly what you are suggesting.

Comment: Based on the code you have provided, you are using socket = io() and then socket.connect(URL) . You either should use socket = io(URL) or socket = io.connect(URL) .